# Xtend: Why isn't compiler generated public Java constructor visible from Xtend code?

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext, xtend

I have a an Xtend subclass `PubnubMessage` that inherits one field and has a constructor generated via active annotation. I can see the public constructor in the generated Java code, and it correctly accepts one argument for the field, but when I try to call that constructor from another Xtend class like so:

```
override successCallback(String channel, Object message)
{
    send(new PubnubMessage(message))
}
```

I get this error on the constructor call:

```
Invalid number of arguments. The constructor PubnubMessage() is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
```

Only the default no-arg constructor is visible, but there shouldn't even be a default constructor since an explicit one is generated. If I make a Java class with the same call:

```
new PubnubMessage(message);
```

There is no error. Here is the relevant code:

SocketMessage.xtend

```
@JsonData class SocketMessage
{
    Object message
}
```

SocketMessage.java (Xtend generated)

```
@JsonData
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class SocketMessage {
  private final Object message;

@JsonCreator
public SocketMessage(@JsonProperty final Object message) {
  super();
  this.message = message;
}
```

PubnubMessage.xtend

```
@JsonData class PubnubMessage extends SocketMessage {}
```

PubnubMessage.java (Xtend generated)

```
@JsonData
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class PubnubMessage extends SocketMessage {
  @JsonCreator  
  public PubnubMessage(@JsonProperty final Object message) {
    super(message);
}
```

I've left out the generated hashCode(), equals(), and toString(). Everything about this Java code seems fine to me, and like I said, I can successfully call it from other Java classes, but not from Xtend.

Comment: Is the class that produces the error 'The constructor PubnubMessage() is not applicable for the arguments (Object)' in a project that has a dependency to the active annotation project?

Comment: If the active annotations project is `org.eclipse.xtend.lib.macro` then yes, it's included as a transitive Maven dependency.

Comment: Is it common to get bogus type errors from Eclipse when running the Xtend plugin? I've had several times now where there's a type mismatch or similar error in Eclipse, but the code still compiles just fine. If it keeps up I should be able to put more specifics on the Bugzilla eventually.

Comment: No, this is quite uncommon. Please file a bugzilla.
The active annotations project is the project where you define your AA. My question aimed at another scenario. Do you have three projects (1 with JsonData, a second with PubnubMessage and a third with this code: 'send(new PubnubMessage(message))'), or only two projects (1 with JsonData and a second with PubnubMessage and the 'send' code)?